# Count object by name in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to count inventories, by location name. All inventories have there location place. 
I did something like this but it doesnt work.

```
$scope.stored = function(name) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
        if($scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){
            count += 1;
        } 
    }
        return count;
    };
```

And in template i put inside location name, currentLocation.name returns selected location name, so passed value is correct.

```
<a ng-click="stored(currentLocation.name)">{{location.name}}</a>

<pre>{{stored}}</pre>
```

My json api where i get all data

```
{
   meta: {
   limit: 20,
   next: null,
   offset: 0,
   previous: null,
   total_count: 3
},
objects: [
{
   assigned: {},
   barcode: "23423432423423",
   count: 1,
   cover: "/media/static/images/tv_3.jpg",
   created: "2014-03-17T10:06:32.309661",
   id: 1,
   location: {
      administrator: {},
      city: "London",
      country: "Afrika",
      id: 1,
      name: "Eriks noliktava",
      postalCode: "1046",
      resource_uri: "/api/v1/location/1",
      street: "Zasulauka iela 11"
},
   manufacturer: "LG",
   model: "M3000",
   resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/1",
   tags: {
   id: 1,
   resource_uri: "/api/v1/tags/1",
   tags: "TV"
}
},
{
   assigned: {},
   barcode: "888",
   count: 1,
   cover: "/media/static/images/no-image.png",
   created: "2014-03-17T12:14:58.833429",
   id: 2,
   location: {
      administrator: {},
      city: "Riga",
      country: "Latvia",
      id: 2,
      name: "Martina noliktava",
      postalCode: "1050",
      resource_uri: "/api/v1/location/2",
      street: "Rigas iela 27"
},
   manufacturer: "Iphone",
   model: "5S",
   resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/2",
   tags: {
   id: 2,
   resource_uri: "/api/v1/tags/2",
   tags: "Phone"
}
},
```

Comment: you can do this to display it in a template `<pre>{{stored(currentLocation.name)}}</pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have counted and return values to `ng-click` event. Instead you can store it inside scope.

```
 var count = 0;
 // Calculate count
 // Assign the count to $scope
 $scope.count = count;
```

Then use `count` anywhere in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code so it is working, if somebody needs.

```
$scope.stored = function(name) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
        if($scope.inventories[i].location.name == name){
           $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
        } 
    }
    return $scope.count;
};
```

And in template

```
{{stored(currentLocation.name)}}
```